# Parallel port with C#

Tags: c#, c++, parallel-port, lpt

I am trying to send data to LPT1 port with a C# program, unfortunately with no success..
I am using windows 7 x64.
I tried both x86 and x64 (inpoutx64.dll) dll's..

With the x64 dll when I send:

```
Output(888, 255);
```

It just continues the program as everything went ok, but i can't see anything on my multimeter (only the static 0.02V)..

I also tried the following with C++:

```
int main () {
int val = 0;
printf("Enter a value\n");
scanf("%d", &val);
_outp(0x378, val);
getchar();
_outp(0x378, 0);
return 0; }
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01281428 in ppac.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

I remember once I made something like this work on xp (C# not the C++ code), I hope it's possible on win7 too..
Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An IO port in the sense used by `_outp` isn't the same as what you're trying to do with a parallel port. An IO port is a processor-level way to get raw access to different devices. The use of IO ports with `_outp` is supposed to be the kind of thing device drivers do. It is therefore privileged (i.e. kernel only) in [any version of windows that's modern enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/733szwah%28VS.80%29.aspx) to have good kernel/userspace separation (namely anything based on Windows NT). I'm almost 100% certain you never got `_outp` to work on XP.

To access the parallel port in high-level code, just open it like a normal file, using the filename `LPT1:`.

Comment: It was possible under XP but only after installing a device driver (that opened all ports IIRC).

Comment: I meant the C# version was working.. it wasn't really clear.. edited now.

Accessing it as a file - doesn't really work for me.. C# says:

FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path.

Comment: @Michael: `inpoutx64.dll` has a kernel-mode driver embedded inside it that  exposes the raw port interface to user-mode programs. (See http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/How_Inpout32.dll_works_.html). That's why your C# program worked on XP.

Comment: So can you suggest another way of doing this? Which will work on win7?