# Does inpout32.dll/inpoutx64.dll handle I/O to/from all parallel ports?

Tags: c#, windows, driver, parallel-port

Days of research and programming have led me to try all variants of inpout32.dll and inpoutx64.dll: binaries, source code, 32-bit, 64-bit, address wrappers.  None work: no change is seen to the output bits of the port.

However, I know it is possible, because using another commercially available program that does parallel port output, I can detect a trigger (state change) on all eight output bits (D0-D7) by passing a value between 0 and 255, exactly what I want to do in my own application.

I have followed all the advice from at least these pages:

- [Write to parallel port in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138393/write-to-parallel-port-in-windows-7)
- [C# LPT inpout32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607935/c-sharp-lpt-inpout32-dll)
- [C# - Read Parallel Port State (Simple Push Switch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501655/c-sharp-read-parallel-port-state-simple-push-switch)
- [Write to a parallel port on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673517/write-to-a-parallel-port-on-windows-7)
- [Parallel port with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940371/parallel-port-with-c-sharp)
- http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit; and my SIIG Cyberpro port is mapped as LPT3 at address 0xCCD8, with four status bits at address 0xCCD4.  I have another ECP printer port mapped as LPT1 at 0x0378, but that does not work either.

I know better than to try direct _inp(), _outp() calls on Win7.

Can anyone help?

If I need to download and modify the driver code, I can do that if I have to, but I think it should not be that difficult.

My final version of code uses 32-bit compilation, interfacing to inpout32.dll:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ParallelPort
{
    public class PortAccess
    {
        //inpout.dll

        [DllImport("inpout32.dll")]
        private static extern void Out32(ushort PortAddress, short Data);

        [DllImport("inpout32.dll")]
        private static extern short Inp32(ushort PortAddress);

        private ushort _PortAddress = 0;

        public ushort PortAddress { get { return _PortAddress; } }

        public PortAccess(ushort portAddress)
        {
            _PortAddress = portAddress;

            short result = 0;
            try
            {
                result = Inp32(portAddress);
            }
            catch (DllNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find InpOut32.dll");
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException)
            {
                result = 0;
            }

            if (0 == result)
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to open parallel port driver");
        }

        //Public Methods
        public void Write(ushort Data)
        {
            Out32(_PortAddress, (short)Data);
        }

        public byte Read()
        {
            return (byte)Inp32(_PortAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making the standard mistake of not explaining how you *know* it doesn't work.  It the term "open collector output" doesn't mean anything to you then head over to electronics.stackexchange.com and ask how to check if a parallel port works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was tired. I forgot.  The answer is: I have a second computer with a data reader/collector that shows each parallel port output bit as a colored line on a moving timed graph.  Using some commercial software that writes to the port, I can pick a one-byte value to write; I can set and identify each bit individually on the graph.  Using my software (that mirrors the proprietary commercial software), I see no output appear, even though I do the "same" thing as the commercial software, write a single byte.  I have no way of finding out how the comm-sw does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:

When I added

```
 [DllImport("inpout32.dll")]
 private static extern void DlPortWritePortUshort(ushort PortAddress, ushort Data);
```

and called that function rather than Out32(ushort addr, ushort value) the code worked.

I don't know why the exact interface matters, but it does; and perhaps that is indeed because of sign extension on the 16-bit port address, as suggested [somewhere TBD].